Azure function app .Net 8 version not mapping the connection string value of ServiceBusTrigger
Connection string loaded from AzureKeyVault and loaded successfully. I can able access it using config["somekey"]. In the function app will map the available in the configuration by default. It working fine with whatever loaded from the json file. But facing the issue whatever loaded from the keyvault.
I have tried put the connection string in the json file. its working as expected. when I removed from the json file and loaded from keyvault not working as expected.

You have to give access to Azure Function and do the Key Vault reference, so that it uses the Key Vault to get the connection string stored as secret.

Managed identity should be enabled for Function app.
To get the secret, i have used below command and followed Microsoft-Document:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecretname/)

Then in Function App:

